# Detectar cuando se cierra un proceso externo en VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

Estoy haciendo una app que en un momento abre una ventana de cmd que ejecuta un comando, y lo que quiero hacer es que la app detecte cuando se cierra esa ventana de cmd y que de ahí abra otro cmd con otro comando, porque si lo hago asi:

```
LabelPaso.Text = "Paso 1 de 3"
Process.Start("cmd.exe", "<comando aqui>")
ProgressBar1.Increment(30)
LabelPaso.Text = "Paso 2 de 3"
Process.Start("cmd.exe", "<comando aqui>")
ProgressBar1.Increment(30)
LabelPaso.Text = "Paso 3 de 3"
Process.Start("cmd.exe", "<comando aqui>")
ProgressBar1.Increment(40)
```

va a ejecutar todo de una y lo que quiero hacer es que vaya ejecutando uno por uno

¿Cuál es la manera para hacer eso?

Comment: Prueba usando [WaitForExit](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.waitforexit?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-6.0#System_Diagnostics_Process_WaitForExit_System_Int32_)

Comment: @Pikoh Gracias, usando este codigo me funciono bien [enlace de donde saque el codigo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6346755) ahora si, como hago para pasarle comandos al cmd, porque con el process start que puse en la pregunta no me deja